# How to transform a 'bat' directive from Jenkinsfile for execution in the Script Console?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

A 'bat' script from my Jenkinsfile is failing for no apparent reason. I already tested it by physically running it on the agent machine, so now I want to run it under Jenkins manually - through the Script Console. How do I go about transforming this line into the exactly equivalent console command?

```
bat 'set \"ANDROID_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\" && gradlew.bat assembleDebug'
```

I tried this, no luck, I probably didn't escape something correctly, perhaps too many inner quotes for the `cmd /c` command?

```
println "cmd \\c \"set \"ANDROID_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\" && gradlew.bat assembleDebug\" ".execute().text
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it's due to the fact that you changed something like `'A"B"C'` to `"A"B"C"` -- whereas in first case you had the `B` par quoted, in the second case it's the `A` and `C` that are enclosed in quotes.

Comment: @DanMašek: Good point indeed. I think I quoted the argument to `cmd \c` wrong, the Groovy part itself may be correct as all the inner quotes are escaped.

Comment: Indeed `cmd \c` should be `cmd /c`, and you can also return the command output by appending `.text` to `.execute()`. From my experience the best way to test a failing step in a pipeline is to copy it to a temporary pipeline to isolate the problem, because the script console doesn't integrate CPS or sandboxes your code.

Comment: @towel: thank you, both good points, and I think it's the sand-boxing that prevents my script from working properly, but I need to experiment and try something in order to find out how to make it work, right?

Comment: @towel: and indeed, this does work, and by "work" I mean in all senses - it does not fail the same way that the real Jenkinsfile does. Oh well. Mind posting your tips as an answer?

Comment: Example: `println "cmd /c \"set\"".execute().text`

Comment: Done. Thanks :) You actually don't need to `println` the output, as `text` returns a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd \c` should be `cmd /c`, and you can also return the command's output like so:

```
"cmd /c \"set \"ANDROID_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\" && gradlew.bat assembleDebug\"".execute().text
```

Anyway, the script console is only the first step to determining run-time issues in pipeline steps, as you only get to know whether the command itself works.

Next you want to isolate your problem in a separate pipeline, so you can work out CPS and sand-boxing problems. Fun stuff.